# Measure stored procedure duration

Tags: stored-procedures, datareader, duration

In my application I want to know the execution time for a stored procedure. 
My pattern is to execute reader and get the data reader and read the results. The reader return immediately and I don’t know the stored procedure execution time. 
I cannot put the timers after the reader because I want to have an extension method to encapsulate just the execute reader call.
Do you have any idea how I can achieve that?

Thanks, 
Radu

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Was your question answered? If so please make it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with a datareader because the datareader won't actually get the data untill you start reading from it.